# Grails - cascading save through class field

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

Not exactly a good explanation in the title, so let's try to do it better:

I have two classes like this:

```
Class A {
  B bObject
....
}

Class B {

static belongsTo = [a: A]
}
```

and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
B b = new B(...)
A a = new A(...)
a.bOject = b
```

if I have onError = false in the configuration, I get a transient exception. If I have onError = true I get a validation error because *a* is false on class B

How to get around like this?

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
 a.setB(B);
 b.setA(A) ;
```

instead of

```
a.bOject = b
```